# Move items between ListModels

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Assume a QML application with two list models, each holding, say 3, items. Graphically the two lists are displayed in two containers. I'd like to implement a drag-and-drop functionality to reorder the items inside their list and to swap two items between different lists.

Reordering in one list poses no problem due to the `move` method of the `ListModel`. For swapping items between the two list models, however, I think I have to use the `remove` and `insert` or `set` operations of `ListModel`. First experiments using `set` didn't work.

What is the canonical way to achieve this that also works with transitions? (E.g. just swapping the items' roles is no solution, I will have to swap the items themselves.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`ListModel.get()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method) to fetch an element from one view and [`ListModel.append()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#append-method) or [`ListModel.insert()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#insert-method) to put it in another one (not exactly with same type)

The simple example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        fillModel(model1);
        fillModel(model2);
    }

    Component {
        id: delegate
        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            property int itemIndex: index
            property var view: ListView.view
            color: (itemIndex === view.currentIndex) ? "orange" : "white"
            height: 20
            Text { text: name; color: moved ? "red" : "black"; anchors.centerIn: parent }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    view.currentIndex = itemIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListView {
            id: list1
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            model: ListModel { id: model1 }
            delegate: delegate
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
            width: 50
            Button { text: ">>>"; onClicked: moveItem(list1,list2) }
            Button { text: "<<<"; onClicked: moveItem(list2,list1) }
        }
        ListView {
            id: list2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            model: ListModel { id: model2 }
            delegate: delegate
            add: Transition {
                id: list2Transition
                enabled: false
                property int fromX
                property int fromY
                ParallelAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "x"; from: list2Transition.fromX; duration: 300;  }
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "y"; from: list2Transition.fromY; duration: 300;easing.type: Easing.OutCirc;  }
                    PropertyAnimation {property: "color"; from: "red"; to: "white"; duration: 500 }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function fillModel(model) {
        for(var i = 0;i < 15;i ++)
            model.append({name: "item" + i, moved: false});
    }
    function moveItem(listfrom,listto) {
        var item = listfrom.model.get(listfrom.currentIndex);
        var newPos1 = listfrom.parent.mapFromItem(listfrom,0,listfrom.currentIndex * 20);
        var newPos2 = listto.parent.mapFromItem(listto,0,listto.currentIndex * 20);
        list2Transition.fromX = newPos1.x - newPos2.x;
        list2Transition.fromY = newPos1.y;
        list2Transition.enabled = true;
        item.moved = true;
        listto.model.insert(listto.currentIndex, item);
        listfrom.model.remove(listfrom.currentIndex, 1);
    }
}
```

You can also do the same action by using drag & drop functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the complete example code! What does not work in a way I'd like, though, is the transition animation when one item is moved from one side to the other. I think In your code in ' moveItem' the identity of the item is lost when you insert the item as the `insert` method accepts only a plain `jsobject` dict.

Comment: You didn't point clearly what you want to achieve. Sure, you can insert item with `Transition`. The problem is to find coordinates of transition beginning. I've updated my example with simple workaround for the problem. Try to move an item from left to right to see that.